Difference between analogue and digital (smart) MEMS microphones
I think that Analog and Digital MEMS, Microphone Design, Considerations by Jerad Lewis, Analog Devices, Technical Article MS-2472 might answer my question. I'll try to sum up:

Analog MEMS mic = transducer + analogue amplifier on board
Digital MEMS mic = analog MEMS mic + ADC + codec + serialisation (like PDM or "better": I2S) (ie. a digital MEMS mic "contains" an analogue MEMS mic plus an ASIC)
Just some mixed mic system = Analog MEMS mic + external codec (like
Atomic Echo Base with Microphone and Speaker which has a
MSM381A3729H9BPC mic plus the ES8311 codec.)

Is this a too simplified summary?

Digital MEMS are mostly PDM: they are a good choice if your processor has dedicated PDM input(s). Implementing a manual PDM decoder using a GPIO pin (or flexible enough serial interface), is a bit of a pain. This may be easier to answer if you explain your specific application and what trade offs you are interested in.

My box is a listening for in-box recorded up to 8 sounds of 1 sec each that gives an alarm output when a sound is heard. Too? much about it at https://www.teigfam.net/oyvind/home/my-beep-brrr-pages/. The first version uses a "mic board" from XMOS with 7 PDM mics, using their lib_mic_array for the X2 with no PDM HW but 8 logical cores one per 4 mics per 2 tiles. It delivers a 384 kHz data stream per mic with no disturbing between the cores, so that I can use 6+8. On the second I use a digital mic ICS-52000 where I poll at 2.048 MHz in one core. I need to understand the diffs of terms here.

I think as a summary, it works fine.

Digital MEMS mic = analog MEMS mic + ADC + codec + serialisation (like PDM…

Note that PDM is kind of the "natural" output of a delta-sigma converter, i.e., there's no extra serialization.

or "better": I2S

Even here, my guess is that the data leaving the part you'd call "ADC" would already be serial; no need to convert to a parallel data bus first if your ADC architecture isn't inherently parallel, and for audio sampling rates, chances are the ADC architecture of choice is delta-sigma (see above) or SAR, so the binary digits are generated serially, anyways! (in fact, I checked ST and Infineon higher-end MEMS microphone datasheets, and both use delta-sigma converters: that makes sense. Conversion speed is not as much of a problem as noise, and delta-sigma have the noise shaping property that makes them desirable for this kind of use case.)
Note that I have limited insight into how MEMS microphones are actually "read" internally; they are technically condenser microphones, so you could either go the classical "electret" route (and I guess that's what's commonly done) to consider them very high-impedance varying voltage sources, hence combine them with a high-performance amplifier and digitize the output of that. Or you could consider the MEMS membrane an adjustable capacitor in itself, and use an excitation frequency much higher than audio range to read the capacitance directly. Downside of that is higher complexity, upside would be that you don't need as low-noise an amplifier.
Infineon definitely goes the first way:

Block diagram from Infineon IM72D128V01 MEMS microphone.

Thanks, Marcus! Very clarifying text and figure! Maybe to add that when PDM is used for my first version, the SW needs to do decimation. (But XMOS also has a delay block to handle direction). About this, for any next version I have been looking around and that's when the analog/digital mic terms often appeared. Good to learn that my attempt at summary was ok!
